# Spring MVC REST API to Filter/Search from Collection

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, restful-url

I have a REST service /accounts which returns all the accounts data (Number, Name).

**Requirement :**
Should Support the below search/filter pattern with any combination of "And" or "OR" rather than retruning the entire collection.

- startsWith
- endsWith
- Contains

Question 1 : Are these below API design correct(RESTful) or any better way to do the same
e.g -

```
/accounts?name^My Account 123**or**number~ACC1234
```

(^"==> Starts with , "~"==> ends with)

```
/accounts?name^My Account 123**and**number~ACC1234
```

(^"==> Starts with "~"==> ends with)

```
/accounts?name$ACC123
```

($ ==> account collection contains ACC123)

**Spring Controller:**

Planning to get these Filter (Query Parameter) pattern as `@RequestParam` and have a Regex to parse the pattern and then apply & retrieve it from the data store. The downside is any new filter pattern would need a change in the Controller class.

**Question 2:** Is there any out of the box features available in Spring 3 to do search / filter from a collection?

Thanks!

Comment: why not use apache solr that is available as module in spring  as spring data solr for your reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using query parameters?

Answer (score 1):

From a design perspective, using Query parameters to specify search / filter parameters is fine. However, for more complex cases such as yours, I typically define a new end point, that only deals with searches.

As an example, if my logic for search is strictly "or" and "contains", I would define a book search as such:

```
GET /books/?author=john&keywords=how%20to%20use%20spring
```

Here, my API is strictly going to search for books where the author's name contains "john" and the words "how to use spring" appear in the content. The Search logic stays consistent, and the client has no flexibility.

In your case, if the client has the ability to specific their own search criteria, you need to build out a new end point, something like:

```
POST /books/search
```

And in the request body, post your own search criteria DSL like `name^My Account 123**and**number~ACC1234`